# Take an array and return "n" elements, as evenly spaced as possible

Tags: php, array

I get the following correct results from this code, but it seems incredibly clunky to me. Is there anything I could be doing more elegantly? The results can be imprecise - as long as it's the right number of returned elements, and the selection is mostly right.

```
$_5elements = array(1,2,3,4,5);
$_10elements = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10);
$_14elements = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14);
$_40elements = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40);
$_140elements = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,60,61,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,69,70,71,72,73,74,75,76,77,78,79,80,81,82,83,84,85,86,87,88,89,90,91,92,93,94,95,96,97,98,99,100,101,102,103,104,105,106,107,108,109,110,111,112,113,114,115,116,117,118,119,120,121,122,123,124,125,126,127,128,129,130,131,132,133,134,135,136,137,138,139,140);    

function spread_array($array = null, $target_array_length = 10) {
    if ($array) {
        $array_length = count($array);
        if ($array_length > $target_array_length) {
            $return = array();
            $division = round( $array_length / $target_array_length );
            krsort($array);
            foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
                if (($key === count($array) - 1 || $key % $division === 0) && count($return) < $target_array_length) {
                    $return[] = $value;
                }
            }
            $return = array_reverse($return);
        } else {
            $return = $array;
        }
        return $return;
    }
    return false;
}

echo "<pre>".print_r(spread_array($_5elements), true)."</pre>";
echo "<pre>".print_r(spread_array($_10elements), true)."</pre>";
echo "<pre>".print_r(spread_array($_14elements), true)."</pre>";
echo "<pre>".print_r(spread_array($_40elements, 20), true)."</pre>";
echo "<pre>".print_r(spread_array($_140elements), true)."</pre>";

/* Results
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 3
    [3] => 4
    [4] => 5
)
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 3
    [3] => 4
    [4] => 5
    [5] => 6
    [6] => 7
    [7] => 8
    [8] => 9
    [9] => 10
)
Array
(
    [0] => 5
    [1] => 6
    [2] => 7
    [3] => 8
    [4] => 9
    [5] => 10
    [6] => 11
    [7] => 12
    [8] => 13
    [9] => 14
)
Array
(
    [0] => 3
    [1] => 5
    [2] => 7
    [3] => 9
    [4] => 11
    [5] => 13
    [6] => 15
    [7] => 17
    [8] => 19
    [9] => 21
    [10] => 23
    [11] => 25
    [12] => 27
    [13] => 29
    [14] => 31
    [15] => 33
    [16] => 35
    [17] => 37
    [18] => 39
    [19] => 40
)
Array
(
    [0] => 15
    [1] => 29
    [2] => 43
    [3] => 57
    [4] => 71
    [5] => 85
    [6] => 99
    [7] => 113
    [8] => 127
    [9] => 140
)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## *Ding!!*

**I've got it!**

So, I have been looking at this code for quite a while now, because *I knew* there had to be some ingenious way to do this. It seemed all to simple to need something of the opposite scale! And, after playing around, sure enough, I think I got it to it's best.

However! I'd hate to just give away the answer without a bit of some code critiquing beforehand. *Shall we begin?...*

---

I sure hope you didn't spend to long typing out those arrays. That'd would have been a bummer! Let's take advantage of a little resource, I like to call it the *[fill-numeric-array-o-matic](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.range.php)*. Switch that baby on, and bam, you get this beautiful babe:

```
$_5elements = range(1, 5);
$_10elements = range(1, 10);
$_14elements = range(1, 14);
$_40elements = range(1, 40);
$_140elements = range(1, 140);
```

Ain't she a beaut'?

**Alright, next step!** I see you countin' up the input array a couple times, good thing we know [how to handle this](http://www.bountytowels.com/)! That's right, it needs to [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) out.

```
$array_length = count($array);
```

Feel free to replace all those nasty repetitions now!

**After** we've dried up that spill, let's knock off [this arrow nonsense](http://blog.codinghorror.com/flattening-arrow-code/) and whip up some clean lookin' code!

Watch ladies and gentlemen as we turn this snippet:

> ```
> if ($array) {
>     $array_length = count($array);
>     if ($array_length > $target_array_length) {
>         ...
>         foreach (...) {
>             if (...) {
>                 $return[] = $value;
>             }
>         }
>         $return = array_reverse($return);
>     } else {
>         $return = $array;
>     }
>     return $return;
> }
> return false;
> ```

into this gorgeous <strike>girl</strike> piece of code!

```
$array_length = count($array);

if ($array_length == 0) {
    return false;
}

if ($array_length <= $target_array_length) {
    return $array;
}

*insert top secret algorithm here*

return array_reverse($output);
```

I hope we all got to see this amazing transformation, the original having layers and layers, `if`s and `else`s all over! To now, a clean and concise workflow...

**Up next!** The end is near, I promise! Before though, let's have a look at these formats and styles. Your code's fashion is really last year... *Everyone's* <strike>shopping at</strike> using 2014 standards.

Seriously though, applying and sticking to a style will benefit everyone. I highly recommend something such as [PHP-FIG](http://www.php-fig.org/) or the [Zend Standards](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.10/en/coding-standard.coding-style.html).

It's mostly just your naming conventions in this code that are goofy, and I have made some changes in my code below.

**Last but not least, the algorithm!** No offense, but your loop plus the conditions made everything so hard to follow. Debugging it to figure out what it did what gave me a headache. <sub>Good thing I have aspirin.</sub>

I found your choice of [`krsort()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php) unnecessary. Well, I've been able to completely remove this!

Now, here's a list of requirements that must be achieved when we do the work:

1. The amount of numbers returned MUST be equal to the number specified.
2. The interval between numbers MUST be as even as possible throughout the list.
3. The highest integer has priority in the output over the lowest numbers. (Assumed this one based on your output)

I'm going to use a funky lookin' `for` loop to go through the array. It's going to look confusing at parts, but I'll do my best to <strike>make it worse</strike> clear things up!

```
$output = [];
$ratio = round($array_length / $target_array_length);
for ($index = $array_length - 1; count($output) < $target_array_length; $index -= $ratio) {
    $output[] = $array[$index];
}

return array_reverse($output);
```

How ya like them apples! Alrighty, let's see what I've done here:

1. Make a new `$output` array to hold our output.
2. Find the `$ratio` at which we should go through the array at. This will cross off the evenly spaced requirement!
3. We're going to set `$index` to one less than the original array's length. We do this so we can reference the highest index and not have an out of bounds error.
4. Throughout the loop, check to make sure we have less in our output array than we want. If we have the right amount, break the loop. Cross off Req. #1!
5. For each iteration, reduced our index by that ratio we came up with earlier.

Inside the loop, add to our output the value from `$array`  with the index that has been decreasing in the loop.

Reverse it to get the desired direction, and there ya have it!

Here's the full code that I came up with. Naming and all! *I call this one: Make-sorted-and-spread-out-array-inator.*

```
$arrayLength5 = range(1, 5);
$arrayLength10 = range(1, 10);
$arrayLength14 = range(1, 14);
$arrayLength40 = range(1, 40);
$arrayLength140 = range(1, 140);

function spreadOutArray(array $array, $targetOutputLength = 10) {

    $originalArrayLength = count($array);

    if ($originalArrayLength == 0) {
        return false;
    }

    if ($originalArrayLength <= $targetOutputLength) {
        return $array;
    }

    $output = [];
    $interval = round($originalArrayLength / $targetOutputLength);
    for ($index = $originalArrayLength - 1; count($output) < $targetOutputLength; $index -= $interval) {
        $output[] = $array[$index];
    }

    return array_reverse($output);
}
```

I hope the galaxy is better now that this question has one hell of an answer. Live long and prosper. Writing these types of answers will help in your quest to living long and prospering much.

*I'd be happy to clarify anything.*

Comment: This is a beautiful thing. Thank you Alex. While I certainly have a long way to go to properly structure my functions, there wasn't any part of that code (and excellent explanation) that I didn't understand. That sounds like good coding to me!

Do you have any good resources on producing this kind of logical, simple and readable code?

Comment: I thought that adding a twist of humor and not just writing out fancy acronyms would make it easier to understand :) I'm afraid I can't point you in one single direction. However, I think being an active participant here on Code Review is one of the best things you can do. The top users are a surplus of great info! If you wanna become more active, I suggest you come join us in [the 2nd Monitor](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8595/the-2nd-monitor) :)

Comment: you sound pretty confident that this works but I see no evidence of that.  A working example would be handy.

Comment: @ashleedawg 6.5 years ago I'll admit I was an idiot, and probably shouldn't have been answering with such gusto. If the answer doesn't work, please feel free to edit. I no longer am in the php world and don't have the time to fix right now. I'd delete this but 9 people found it helpful so there must be some value?

Answer (score 4):

**Watch out: The algorithm!**

You round too early. The steps `$interval` should be exact, because if the rounding is upward, the steps will bring you too fast to the start of the array and lead to negative indexes.

So only use `round()` when you use the resulting index:

```
$output = [];
$ratio = $array_length / $target_array_length;
for ($index = $array_length - 1; count($output) < $target_array_length; $index -= $ratio) {
$output[] = $array[round($index)];
}
return array_reverse($output);
```

Another good idea is to replace `round()` with `floor()`.

But if you don't want to write complicated algorithm, just use [`range()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.range.php).

Answer (score 1):

The selected answer looks like to me like it will grab the first 30 elements in an array of 35 elements, rather than truly spread out. What needs to happen is you should loop through the indexes of your TARGET array and then proportionally grab the index of the source array. Here is the solution in javascript, but its convertible to php:

```
export default function condenseArray(array, targetCount) {
  var selected = []
  for (var i = 0; i < targetCount; i++) {
    let percent = i / targetCount
    let idx = Math.round(percent * array.length)
    let obj = array[idx]
    selected.push(obj)
  }

  return selected
}
```

Here are tests to demonstrate how it works:

```
test('gets every other one when condensing in half', function(assert) {
  var array = []
  for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    array.push(i)
  }

  let result = condenseArray(array, 5)
  assert.deepEqual(result,  [0, 2, 4, 6, 8])
})

test('spreads it out a bit when not an multiple', function(assert) {
  var array = []
  for (var i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
    array.push(i)
  }

  let result = condenseArray(array, 5)
  assert.deepEqual(result,  [0, 2, 4, 7, 9])
})
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Please read [How do I write a good answer?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer): "_Every answer must make at least one **insightful observation** about the code in the question._"